# String diff to show positions of changed characters?

Tags: ruby, diff

I'm looking for a way to diff two strings and return the index value of where the changes start and finish.

I'm already using diff-lcs to find out which lines have changed, but I need to figure out the positions of which characters have changed. I need the positions of the new characters so I can handle them with JavaScript, not the actual text, which is what most diff tools seem to give.

So, for example if I have this string:

```
The brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

and compare to this string:

```
The red fox jumps over the crazy dog
```

I would like to see something like:

```
[[5,8],[28,33]]
```

Those numbers being the position where the new characters are found.

Does anyone have any idea how I might get this done?

Comment: We'd like to see what you've tried to solve this.

Comment: ["Diff::LCS computes the difference between two Enumerable sequences using..."](http://rubygems.org/gems/diff-lcs). There's nothing in there that says that "sequences of lines" so why not work with sequences of characters instead?

Comment: Yea, I'm using Diff::LCS , but I cant find anywhere that gives me a real sequence of diff characters.  I can diff two string together and it just tells me position zero all the time.. Even though its somewhere around position 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the Google diff-match-patch code? https://github.com/elliotlaster/Ruby-Diff-Match-Patch

I've used it in the past and been happy with the results.

Taken from the documentation linked above:

```
# Diff-ing
dmp.diff_main("Apples are a fruit.", "Bananas are also fruit.", false)
=> [[-1, "Apple"], [1, "Banana"], [0, "s are a"], [1, "lso"], [0, " fruit."]]
```

You would just need to iterate through the non-matches and find the character position in the appropriate string.

```
pos_ary = s.enum_for(:scan, /search_string/).map { regexp.last_match.begin(0) }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, although the only problem I see with this approach is that many of the strings im diff'ing will be IP Addresses, with maybe a single number changed.  If I regex searched for say the number "1" im bound to find multiple mis-matches on the string.

Comment: Then instead of regex you could step through the `diff_main` result summing the length of the each string?  E.g. "Apple".length + "s are a".length + 1 = first position for 2nd miscompare.  If the number is 0, just add the length.  If it's 1 then add to your diff position array based on the current length sum.

Comment: Yea, im looking into something like that now .. I'll make this as the answer because I think your on the right track, its just my specific use case that im having issues with.